# Without using the Time Hierarchy Theorem, is there any other way to prove P /= EXP

Tags: complexity-theory

I haven't found any way to show this was the case (that P/=EXP, without using the Time Hierarchy Theorem)
If you can find a way to show this, can you give a short explanation of this,and also if possible link a paper supporting  your conclusion.
Thank you so much

Comment: But I have a question Kaban: How exactly did you derive your conclusion from the post you linked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, actually! Kind of.

Consider two cases:

1. $P \not= NP$. This case is easy: then $P \not= EXP$, because $NP \subset EXP$.
2. $P = NP$. It is known that $P = NP$ implies that there is a language from $EXP$ that has circuit complexity of at least $\frac{2^n}{10n}$, so $EXP$ is not a subset of $P/\mathrm{poly}$ in this case, let alone $P$. I will recall the proof here with more details if it is necessary, but that question has already been answered, for example, here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57828/p-np-exp-has-circuit-size-o2n-n (the answer is pretty sketchy, though, so feel free to ask for more details).

Comment: Do we have any evidence that we have either results for the question P vs. NP: P = NP or P != NP? Since it is possible that P vs. NP are independent of axioms of mathematics (like Axiom of Choice). Scott Aaronson (may be others) tried to show for current techniques that have been used to show that a mathematical statement is an independents of mathematical axioms cannot be used for the case of P vs. NP. So it is open that P vs. NP is an independent of mathematical axioms, P = NP, or P != NP. So, I believe that your proof is based on very strong assumption that P = NP or P != NP.